# What is the difference between Mayor and Mayor President?

Tags: word-request

Well...[**after an African American person was shot to death by police in Louisiana,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/louisiana-protestors-call-lafayette-mayor-104533151.html) another chaos succeeding [**the George Floyd's death**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Floyd) is seemingly about to occur.

My question is, I understand the situation, as in the title?

> What is the difference between Mayor and Mayor President?

This is the first time I heard the name of the title Mayor President.

Is there any difference of the role from the Mayor?

Thank you for enlightening me in advance.

Comment: What is a 'blackman'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The City of Lafayette, which had a Mayor, and the Parish of Lafayette, which had a Council President, merged in 1992. It appears that their combined chief executive is called the Mayor-President to reflect that he, in effect, holds both positions.

Comment: Assuming StephenS is right (and it sounds like he is),  it's important to remember that this is a local term, not a normal English term. Most Americans wouldn't know it.

Comment: @codi6 Indeed, I didn’t know it until I checked Wikipedia for details on the city’s politics.